# Z-index greater than Fancybox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fancybox

I have a `div` inside of Fancybox that I want to overflow over the edge of the fancybox window.

The structure of the page looks like this:

```
<div class="fanybox">
    <div class="overflow">
        Test
    </div>
</div>
```

I want `.overflow` to flow over the edge of the window. Trying to change the `z-index` of `.overflow` to something higher than 8030 (the default Fancybox value) does not work, and yes, the `div` is positioned absolutely.

Is there anyway to fix this? I can provide an image of what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: Please show us the non-working code in a demo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't used fancybox, myself, but playing around with the chrome console on their demo page I think I got the effect you are looking for.

-Drop out the overflow:hidden; on #fancybox-content.

```
#fancybox-image (or whatever your container is){
.
.
.
    position:relative;
    right:50px;
    z-index:9000;
}
```

That's all it took for what's on their demo page. Should absolutely be doable as long as your content's parent isn't positioned statically, and the overflow isn't hidden. I'd probably position it relatively (not absolutely) if I understand what you are trying for. Hope that helps.

---

*EDIT*

Alright, I downloaded and got a bare bones page up using fancybox2 from the link provided (because apparently I have too much time on my hands :-). Using all their default values, all I had to change was the jquery.fancybox.css

```
.fancybox-inner {

position:relative;
right:50px;
}
```

and the image floated outside the container div. If you are trying to move a separate div or something you added, principles are the same. But it DOES work... Goodluck.

Comment: I'm not sure this solution works for Fancybox2, which I am using, http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/

Comment: @Charlie see edit. Note, the new class does intentionally leave out the hidden attribute.

Answer (score 0):

If the `overflow` element is inside the `fancybox`, you won't need any `z-index` at all. Every non-`static`-positioned element generates its own stack, and relative-positioned content inside a fancybox will easily overflow its outer elements [[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/P889P/)].